# Scaling predicted data to a range of 0 and 1

Tags: r, scaling, glm, predict

I did a glm in R and predicted a model out of the results I got. The values that I received the `pred$fit`vary between -1.2 and 0.7. However I would like to rescale these values to a range between 0 and 1 so I can observe it on a plot with the Y axis ranging between these 2 values. Changing the ylim is not enough since the negative values will not be seen. Is there a function that can be applied for this case?

Answer (score 0):

do you mean something like this?

```
x <- seq(-1.2,0.7,.1)
as.numeric(cut(x,quantile(x, seq(0,1,.1), include.lowest=T)))/10
```

Comment: `model4=glm(Detection~Camouflage, data,family=binomial)
summary(model4)
anova(model4)
nouv=expand.grid(Camouflage=unique(data$Camouflage))
pred=predict(model4, newdata=nouv, se.fit=T)
nouv$fit=pred$fit
nouv$min=pred$fit-pred$se.fit
nouv$max=pred$fit+pred$se.fit`                     This is what I did, and the values given by the predict function are -1.2 and 0.7. I want these values to vary between 0 and 1 only. I don't want negative value while keeping the gap between the numbers quite the same.